# implement a promise to return the slower of two promises

Tags: es6-promise, asynchronous-javascript

I'm new to asynchronous programming and I'm only getting familiar with the idea of promises as a replacement for callbacks.
I'm trying to implement a function ( promise) to take in two other promises, and that will return the value of the one that took longer to complete only if both completed. 
So basically my idea was to use the Date.now() function to calculate the time it takes for one promise to execute, but I'm having trouble writing it down, especially with a promise that takes in two other promises ( if that's even possible), here's my attempt:

```
var p1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let start = Date.now();
setTimeout(() => 
   resolve(
     {
       id: 0,
       time: Date.now() - start,
       value: 4+3
     }
           ), 500);
})

var p2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let start = Date.now();

  setTimeout(() => 
    reject(
      {
        id: 1,
        time: Date.now() - start,
        value: 7+3
      }
          ), 800);
})
```

This is just an idea, and the promises p1, p2 should be given as arguments to the promise 'slower', the thing I did with Date.now() should somehow be wrapped around the call to these promises, and then I'm hoping to calculate the runtime of both promises and then return the value of the slower one.
Any ideas on how to implement this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one idea for how to do it.  Rather than timestamps, I just used a `cntr`.  The last one (the slowest one) will be tagged with `cntr === 0` so when they're all done, we just fine that one that is tagged with the `0` cntr and return it's val.

```
function promiseSlowAll(arrayOfPromises) {
    let cntr = arrayOfPromises.length - 1;
    let newPromises = arrayOfPromises.map(p => {
        return p.then(val => {
            // wrap the results in an object along with a cntr
            return {val: val, cntr: cntr--};
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(newPromises).then(allResults => {
        const lastResult = allResults.find(item => item.cntr === 0);
        // resolve with a single result from the last promise to finish
        return lastResult.val;
    });
}
```

So, you call `promiseSlowAll()` with an array of promises and you get back a single resolved value that corresponds with the slowest promise to resolve.

Here's a working demo:

```js
function promiseSlowAll(arrayOfPromises) {
    let cntr = arrayOfPromises.length - 1;
    let newPromises = arrayOfPromises.map(p => {
        return p.then(val => {
            // wrap the results in an object along with a cntr
            return {val: val, cntr: cntr--};
        });
    });
    return Promise.all(newPromises).then(allResults => {
        const lastResult = allResults.find(item => item.cntr === 0);
        return lastResult.val;
    });
}

function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}

promiseSlowAll([delay(200, "200"), delay(300, "300"), delay(100, "100")]).then(r => {
    console.log("slowest is", r);
});
```

Comment: So it doesn't matter in which order the promises are in the array? because it looks like it does, it looks like the last promise in the array will get the cntr = 0.

Comment: @sadElephent - Nope, order in the original array doesn't matter here.  Remember, the promises resolve in their own order.  So, `p.then()` gets called when the promises resolve, not in the order they appear in the array and that's where the `cntr` is assigned.  So, the last promise to resolve and call it's `.then()` handler, gets the `cntr === 0`.  Try the demo.  It's the middle one that will be the slowest and end up with `cntr === 0`.  Make a copy into your own file and try different orders to prove it to yourself if you want.

Comment: Thanks! I guess what threw me off is the fact that you're using map, I thought that it would resolve the promises in the right order. Just to be sure, what happens is that map executes synchronously and therefore all of these happen practically at the same time, and what matters is in what order then() is called since this is where the counter is being set right?

Comment: @sadElephent - All the `.map()` does is register the `.then()` handlers and create a new promise from each call to `.then()`.  Calling `.then()` is just  register new event handlers that will then be called sometime in the future when the host promise resolves, long after the `.map()` is done.  The `.map()` is synchronous, but all it does is register a bunch of event handlers.  Those event handlers will be called later in the order that each promise resolves (whatever order that is).

Comment: What if I wanted to make sure all promises actually resolved before returning? How would I go about that?

Comment: @sadElephent - This already waits for all the promises.  The only way to get the value from the slowest one is to wait for that last one.  If ALL you want is to wait for all of them, you just use `Promise.all(arrayOfPromises).then(...).catch(...)`.

Comment: But it wait for them to fulfill right? How do I know if all actually succeeded?

Comment: @sadElephent - This sounds like you would benefit from doing some reading about how promises work and how you handle errors in them.  If your `.then()` handler gets called, it succeeded.  If your `.catch()` handler gets called, it had an error.  The code I'm showing either succeeds with a resolved promise or fails with a rejected promise and the caller needs to listen for both scenarios.

Comment: Yea I thought this was the case, and it does make a lot of sense, I just wasn’t a 100% sure. My bad tough , and thank you !